# Updating a classes' variable in a constructor through pass by reference?

Tags: system-verilog

Blazing ahead with newfound knowledge of SystemVerilog's inner workings I've set out to use one of these fandangled pass-by-reference features to update a classes' counter in the constructor of another class. The setup (stripped to the basics) looks somewhat like this:

```
class my_queue;
  int unsigned num_items; //Want to track the number of items this Queue has seen.

  function push_new_item();
     item new_item = new(num_items);
  endfunction

endclass

class parent_item;
   int unsigned x_th_item;
   function new(ref int unsigned num_items);
      x_th_item = num_items;
      num_items += 1; //This should increase the counter in num_items.
   endfunction
endclass

class item extends parent_item;
   function new(ref int unsigned num_items);
      super.new(num_items);
   endfunction
endclass
```

The issue is that my compiler is complaining about an

```
Illegal connection to the ref port 'num_items' of function/task parent_item::new, formal argument should have same type as actual argument.
```

I have an idea on how to fix this: Moving the increment after the call to new() in push_new_items.
But then I still won't know how to correctly use pass-by-refrence in SV so what's causing the error?
Is it the other pass-by-reference or maybe a syntactical error?

Comment: Shouldn't `x_th_item` also be `unsigned`?

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question. I didn't make this mistake in my SV program though.

Comment: Wait a second... I think I might have made that mistake in my function definitions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qiu did point me to the issue with my code. My problem was that, whilst the variables were declared correctly on both ends, one of my constructors was written:

```
function new(ref int num_items);
```

where it should have rather been

```
function new(ref int unsigned num_items);
```

Thank you Qiu.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need **ref** semantics for this, use an **inout** argument.
**inout**'s are copied-in upon entry and copied-out upon return of a task or function. The type compatibility requirements are much stricter as you have seen for **ref** arguments.

The only occasion you must use a **ref** argument isin time consuming tasks and you need to see active updates to the arguments before the task returns.

```
task my_task(ref bit tclock);
  @(posedge tclock) // this would hang if tclock was an input
endtask
```

Another place you might want to use a ref argument is as an optimization when the argument type is a large object like an array. But passing a single int by reference is actually slower than copying its value directly.

Comment: Very interesting. I was under the impression that input, output and inout were reserved for modules and never bothered to check on that.